# Matrix transform from one coordinate system to another

Tags: matrix, coordinates, maya, unreal-4

I have been beating my head against the wall for weeks on this and it is time I just break down and ask for help.

I need to move a 3D camera from an in house system into Unreal 4.  The two use different coordinate systems.  I thought I could just use a matrix multiplication to convert from one system to the other, but so far I have had no luck finding the magic numbers to do so.

The source system is the same as Maya; Y up, -Z Forward, X right

The destination, Unreal; Z up, X forward, Y right

Besides the different Up axis, there is a LHS/RHS difference as well which is making things more complicated for me.  I am very bad at 3D math and would appreciate any help, and can amend this question with any additional details that are required.

This is the math I am using with any given conversion matrix:

```
newMatrix = conversionMatrix * sourceMatrix * conversionMatrix.Inverse()
```

My source matrices are 4x4, but in Unreal I specify a 3x3, ignoring the last column.

An example source matrix (somewhat rounded):

```
 0.4608        0.0072       -0.8874
-0.4448        0.8671       -0.2239
 0.7679        0.4979        0.4028
 982.0462      1196.9969    -107.6024
```

This represents in Maya approximately:

```
POS: x982.0462, y1196.9969, z-107.6024
ROT: x-29.866, y62.319, z0.479
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Basis_and_coordinates an introduction I wrote on what coordinates are and how matrices let us move between different sets of coordinates. This should let you do it yourself :)

Comment: If you really struggle .... I dunno, but different coordinate schemes are something you'll need to be okay with. But I'll try to help. It should explain what your transforms are doing and how to actually transform! Night.

Comment: I understand the theory, it is more that I can't find any matrix that actually works and I have no idea how to derive the proper matrix.  I thought I would just pre-rotate an object in Maya to match Unreal and then use that Matrix, but it didn't work.

Comment: I need to sleep now, but all you need is a matrix consisting of columns which are where the standard coordinates map to. How can you get the document but not that?!